# Command to check if any updates are pending in Software Updater?

Tags: command-line, updates, update-manager

Sorry if this is a basic question, I did try searching for an answer but I couldn't locate what I was looking for.

Could someone please tell me is there any way I can via command line return a binary yes/no or number count of any pending updates within Software Updater?

Im trying to trigger a flow within my home automation package to proactively alert me when the system needs updating.

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"

thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I've added that info to the original question. thanks

Comment: You need two commands: First, `sudo apt update ` for the number of available upgrades from the repositories. Second, you need `sudo snap refresh --list` this will give you a list of snap apps that are upgradable. You will have to pipe these outputs through something else to get a Yes/No or a number of updates.

Answer (score 1):

To see the current number count of any updates available in Software Updater run:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable | grep immediately | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

The full output can be viewed by running:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```